# How do I clear out a large area of spiders from a monster spawner?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I have made a terrible mistake on cubecraft's SkyBlock.
I have made a spider farm, it is very secure (so no spiders can get out) but i put all of the spawners in one area.
Now, whenever i enter the room (with all the spawners in it) I get swarmed by all the spiders and see the dreaded "you died" screen.
I need to get into the room, destroy the spawners then kill all of the spiders.
I have tried many ways to accomplish this task such as using water, trying my luck with  a sword, building over, under and behind the farm, but none of them have worked so far.
I need a solution to this problem.
For informational purposes;
I am on the fourth island (Jungle),
I have a bane of arthopods sword and a fire aspect sword
and I'm on a solo profile.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, You want to clear the spiders and their spawners. Get a bow and have the Infinity enchantment to destroy the Spawners, After that you could with the same bow kill the spiders or use a sword.. I think that will help.

Comment: I don't think shooting at blocks destroys them.

Comment: Then the only way is to use a break command to break the spawners and then regularly kill the spiders

Comment: But I'm not good at commands soo...

Comment: Mine the spawners? And blow up the spiders with TNT?

Comment: On cubecraft's Skyblock at the stage im at i dont have t5nt

Comment: also im not a mod so i cant use commands